# How to take variable from printf output and define as value of two other variables

Tags: linux, bash, shell, printf

I have a .txt input file that is the product of a printf defining each line as POV(n)="sequenceX,yearY"

```
cat output.PA
POV01="SEQ010,FY15"
POV02="SEQ010,FY16"
POV03="SEQ020,FY15"
POV04="SEQ020,FY16"
```

How can I source this file so that I can export each POV as the variable value of sequence and fy, respectively for the given line?

```
export POV(n)="$seq,$fy"
```

the printf I have used to get tho this point is as follows:

```
cat step1
while read -r seq fy; do
        printf 'POV%02d="%s,%s"\n' ${counter} ${seq} ${fy}
        (( counter = counter + 1 ))
done <test_scenario_02.txt > output.PA
```

If I source output.PA I get the following:

```
./step2
POV00=YEAR,
POV01=SEQ010,FY15
POV02=SEQ010,FY16
POV03=SEQ020,FY15
POV04=SEQ020,FY16
POV05=SEQ030,FY15
POV06=SEQ030,FY16
POV07=SEQ030,FY15
POV08=SEQ030,FY16
POV09=SEQ040,FY15
POV10=SEQ040,FY16
POV11=SEQ050,FY15
POV12=SEQ050,FY16
$ cat step2
. ./output.PA
set | grep "^POV"
```

Comment: Why you keep adding a c tag to this question?

Comment: Please show an example of what the desired output would look like.

Comment: When you say 'export', do you mean 'assign a variable'?  'export' has a specific meaning that does not have any relation to what it appears you are trying to do.

Comment: I am wanting to assign POV 2 variables.....let me give the current situation and maybe that will help explain. Currently we have EXPORT model_POV_(n)="\"$scenario, $year_mbr_name\"", but these are both static, with scenario=%1, and year_mbr_name=fy14, at the top. Now, in the new style ,these wont be static, they will need to be read from the.txt that has all the sequence/year combos, so we need it to be EXPORT POV(n)="\"$sequence, $fy\"" where $sequence and $fy represent each line of the .txt

Comment: The parentheses make me nervous: `export model_pov_(n)="..."` is a syntax error in sh, bash, dash, and ksh.  Are you using zsh?

Comment: its bash right now. Is my question making better sense at all? Basically, each line in the .txt contains a POV selected in a form, that then creates the .txt (SEQUENCE###   YEAR##). I am needing to pull each sequence/year combo, assign to another variable, then export this variable so it can be used in an OWS connection to run a business model based on the selected POVs (hope that helps if you are familiar with EPMA by any chance)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not at all clear what you want, but it seems like you are trying to create an array variable that holds all the value in output.PA.  You probably don't need to do that, but this should work:

```
$ pov=($(sed -e 's/[^"]*"//' -e 's/"$//' output.PA))
$ echo ${pov[0]}
SEQ010,FY15
$ echo ${pov[1]}
SEQ010,FY16
$ echo ${pov[2]}
SEQ020,FY15
```

Comment: I can do the same currently by . ./output.PA    set|grep {"^POV"} echo $POV(N).....I am needing to be able to call these values as variables...i.e. sample_pov="\"$scenario, $year\""........I am new in this space, but if I were to explain in sql, I basically want to be able to say select SEQUENCE, YEAR where POV=POV01, then use these values in an automation script

Comment: That actually does allow me to utilize the results in a way I am needing to, thanks! There are a few tasks here I am trying to complete with various formats, which is why its a bit confusing to explain what I am needing.